# Launch snap applications in Fedora

Tags: fedora, snap

I'm using Fedora 27. Just installed a `snapd` and a snap application - JetBrains DataGrip. But I can't launch it from Applications menu. Icon is available, but when I click on it - it simply doesn't launch. The `.desktop` is available: `/snap/datagrip/current/meta/gui/datagrip.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=DataGrip
Icon=${SNAP}/bin/datagrip.png
Exec=datagrip %f
Comment=The Drive to Develop
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-datagrip
```

Same happened with another GUI application I've tried to run from snap.

I guess I need to add snap in the path somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by running following two commands: `ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap` and `ln -s /usr/libexec/snapd /usr/lib/`. Both commands require `sudo`.

Comment: No need for creating/copying .desktop with those two symlinks, the applications appear in activities menu, super + search  + click.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `run` option to launch the snap application.

```
snap --help
run         Run the given snap command
```

You don't need `sudo`:

```
$ snap run < program >
```

Comment: This is in best case a workaround, IMHO, as it requires a terminal open for each application.

Comment: True, and terminal is still the actual default for Linux; plenty of applications run from terminal - try create a shortcut for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>fx</kbd> login; `cmatrix`. Click and run is usually for gui based operating systems which Fedora clearly is.